# Excel file not being written to

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to write to an Excel file using openXML. I followed [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-text-into-a-cell-in-a-spreadsheet) to do it. There's only a small difference with the code being that I wish to write number values instead of text.

See the code below :

```
public void SetSpreadSheet(string filePath)
        {
            sprdSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true);

            wrkBook = sprdSheet.WorkbookPart;

            wrkSheet = wrkBook.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            wrkSheet.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
            wrkSheet.Worksheet.Save();

            sheets = wrkBook.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            sheet = new Sheet() { Id = wrkBook.GetIdOfPart(wrkSheet), SheetId = 1, Name = "test" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);
        }
```

Here I use `SpreadsheetDocument.Open` instead of creating a new one because I aim to write to an existing Excel template in the future.

```
public void AddData(float data, string columnName, UInt32 rowIndex)
        {
            var row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
            wrkSheet.Worksheet.AppendChild(row);

            Cell cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(columnName, rowIndex, wrkSheet);
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(data);
            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

            wrkSheet.Worksheet.Save();
        }
```

There is another method called `InsertCellInWorksheet` which I took from MSDN example (and decided to not include since it is quite long).

I tested these methods using the following programm:

```
        int column = 10;
        int row = 5;
        var rnd = new Random();

        var xl = new Xl();
        xl.SetSpreadSheet(@"path to the file .xlsx");
        
        for(int c = 1; c <= column; c++)
        {
            for(int r = 1; r <= row; r++)
            {
                var columnName = Number2String(c, true);
                xl.AddData(rnd.Next(10), columnName, (uint)r);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And the result that I get is an empty Excel spreadsheet.
In the MSDN example they use a `SharedStringTablePart` to write to the Excel spreadsheet, is there an object akin to it that I should use to write numerical data ?

**UPDATE**

Following mcalex' comment i tried using [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) and succeeded in doing just what I wanted to do. However, I'm still interested in understanding why my file is not being written to so feel free to answer the question.

Comment: Are you calling Save after you're done modifying it?

Comment: I am calling Save at the end of `AddData()` and right after creating the `WorkSheetPart` int `SetSpreadsheet()`.

Comment: Have you looked at [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)?  Your addData() will look something like: `wrkSheet.Cell(columnName + rowIndex).Value = data;`

Comment: No I haven't but I will look it up, thanks.

Comment: You need to Save or Close your SpreadsheetDocument.

Comment: @AngelYordanov is there a best place to save my spreadsheet ? I just tried saving during and after the for loops and in both cases I get a corrupted Excel file.

Comment: You should save after you are done with it. The corruption may be from incorrectly created xml part. The OpenXml APIs wont stop you from creating an incorrect xml, you should now how to use it. I recommend that you create the desired xlsx file with the Excel app and then unarchive it (its a plain old zip with xlsx extension). And have a look around as to how a correctly formed xlsx should look.